Generate _templ.go through Go instead of the CLI?
While playing around with Templ, generating a template would produce
./views
  ./layout.templ
  ./layout_templ.go

Is it possible to manually specify the target location of these generated files? Or even control the output names?
Ideally, because I already use some custom dev tools for code generation, manually parsing and generating templates through user code would be preferable. Something like:
import (
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
   
    "github.com/a-h/templ"
)

func CompileTemplate(source string, targetPath string) error {
   content, err := os.ReadFile(source)
   if err != nil {
     return err
   }

   file := filepath.Base(path)
   ext := filepath.Ext(file)
   targetFile := file[:len(file)-len(ext)] + ".go"
   targetFilePath := filepath.Join(targetPath, targetFile)

   // parse and compile...
   // write compiled template to targetFilePath

   return nil
}

Is this possible?

@KavehShahbazian I don't see how this applies to the question, here :/

For those interested, I have this working solution:
// import "github.com/a-h/templ/cmd/templ/generatecmd"

func GenerateTemplate(filename string) (bytes.Buffer, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    r, w, pipeErr := os.Pipe()

    if pipeErr != nil {
        return buf, pipeErr
    }

    old := os.Stdout
    os.Stdout = w // intercept everything to stdout

    genErr := generatecmd.NewGenerate(slog.Default(), generatecmd.Arguments{
        FileName: filename,
        ToStdout: true,
    }).Run(context.Background())

    w.Close()
    defer r.Close()

    os.Stdout = old // restore stdout

    if genErr != nil {
        return buf, genErr
    }

    io.Copy(&buf, r)

    return buf, nil
}

